# Is my use of Enums as a couple value a bad practice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, uniqueidentifier, loose-coupling

For context, using C# inside the Unity3D Editor.

I have more and more often started using enums to loosely couple things to settings.

For example i am setting up an item, and i want to give it a visual from a pool of defined visuals. That visual is basically a class that contains a sprite, a color, and a model attached to an integer unique ID. From this Unique ID, i generate an Enum. And it takes some effort to verify that the UniqueID is actually Unique, and catch some edge cases regarding that.

The benefit of doing the above, is that the enum is all that has to be stored on the item, to link it to the visual. At runtime there is a dictionary created to lookup the enum, and then request the stored visual to be loaded/used. This loosely couples the visuals to the item, so loading the item list does not automatically load all of the visual assets associated with the item. The last part is unity default behavior and is really annoying, and it really slows down the game and consumes a massive amount of RAM in this default behavior.

As a result we have a lot of those enums for various purposes and a lot of lookup stuff happening. And currently we are having no big problems with it.

However, the enums and the editing/generation of those enums is error prone in the sense that when values are removed, the items (and any other interested parties) are non the wiser, which then has to be either tested before build, or runs into a safety catch/error at runtime.

My question is. Is this a blatant abuse of Enums? And if so, what would be a better way of approaching this problem of loose coupling? 
If it is not, what would be a better way to set up and manage these enums in a safe way? So alarm bells will go off if anything using the enum now has an invalid value, or the values meaning would change? Which i imagine is hardly possible, and requires code all over the place to "self check" on recompile?

Or does this just all boil down to team discipline to manage the values well, and know what the enums mean and represent? In which case, it would never be able to make this designer friendly unless i write a custom editor for each and every one of these.

Thanks for any insights you might be able to provide.

Comment: Maybe use a small database for the item and graphics combinations?  
(use sqlite or litedbfor example) 
I would think that an "link table" (just UID of the graphic and the UID of the item per row) would be more effective (and you can create a more dynamic system).

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd that might actually be a good suggestion especially for lookup. But it would also mean that instead of generating the enum (which is currently just a simple method that takes a name and a list of int/string pairs to generate) would have to actually drop/rebuild the table. It does not solve the issue with setup/changes however. Or at least it stays the same as that is now with enums.

Comment: To add to this, items will be randomly generated, and as such they do not really have a unique ID themselves. Making this lookup a tad harder to work with.

Comment: True, but I think with some small tweaks a DB is a better solution than a Enum for randomly generated assets. Mostly because then you can automate (almost) everything.
Also if you have a DB you can automate the check for missing assets. and remove the corresponding rows to prevent some of the errors.

Comment: That again would not improve much on the workflow. The exception being that the database can probably generate a log that tells us what references got removed from what other tables/links.
Question is though, how would you add a table that links visuals to the at runtime uniquely generated items? Just generate a hash for them and hope they never clash?

Comment: The database can generate an unique ID which wont clash, for sqlite it is an autoincrement column in the table and in litedb (nosql variant of sqlite) it generates one if you define an ID (guid) column and don't assign a value. (these are always unique) this will remove some of the load from the code you need to maintain

Comment: Ah, obviously. My lack of database knowledge is showing. I will look into using this for future projects. As it would indeed make a lot of sense if we build a neat wrapper around it for our preferred use.

Comment: Could you achieve the same with a class.. e.g. a set of static read-only accessors (getters) with the same names as your enums, that returns the appropriate combination?  Using this method allows you to customize the result generated by each getter, and allows you to ensure they are initialized before being(and only when) used.  It also eliminates the need for a database/lookup-array, as each getter's functionality is hard-coded.  Obviously this looses the flexibility of a database, but not-more, I think, than using enums to identify & specially-initialize each database element

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to associate each item with one of multiple static visuals? If this is the case you can simply write each visual as a static readonly object inside the visuals class. In your "item" objects you can then make a field called e.g. "visual" and set this to reference the right visual.

I don't know what makes the visuals load, but if the constructor does, then I believe they will load when the visual class is first used at runtime.

Comment: It's unity, the visual when hard linked like your example, would result in them trying to load whenever the item data class is constructed. So in the case of loading an inventory of items from a save file. All 100 of them, and once, on constructor. You can't really get around that functionality either. that is why i use this loose coupling in the first place.

Comment: @Smileynator Do you mean that the visuals should only when (and if) they are used? If so you can do this using the System.Lazy<Visual> class. If you reference a Lazy<Visual> instead of a Visual, the value of the field wont be calculated until the first time you use it. (Assuming the Visuals are loaded on at their construction)

Comment: So instead you could store a set of static readonly Lazy<Visual>. In the item class you can have a function or method, getVisual, that simply returns myLazyVisual.Value

Comment: This concept is called [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), by the way.

Comment: I did not know that, so i learned something new. Problem is that i still want to serialize my items. And storing a reference through an integer, is 10x smaller than storing visual references for each of the 100's of items. Also, i think Unity wouldn't want to work with it either way :P

Comment: @Smileynator Well, this should work in theory, at least. If you want to use a more complex solution, I recommend using the nameOf() and typeOf() operators to avoid having to do shotgun surgery.

Comment: Also, if you want shorter integers for the references I guess you could give them custom IDs by hand. Altho you'd have to make tests to see if you accidentaly make some that overlap.